# How to get console output using Polymer?

Tags: polymer

I have this part of code inside `dom-module` tag:

```
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "hi-world",
      properties:{
        name: {
          type: String,
          value: "default";
        },
        edad: {
          type: Number;
        },
        created: function(){
          console.log("The element was created")
          console.log(this)
          console.log(this.$)
          console.log(this.$.title);
        }
      }
    })

  </script>
```

But when I execute the code, nothing happens in console at Chrome, Firefox or even (sorry about this) IE. What am I doing wrong? I see some guide lines at https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements, but it doesn't work.

Also, I tried with one line `console.log`, with:

```
created: function(){
  console.log("The element was created");
}
```

And, again, no results in web browser console.

**EDIT 1:**
According to a1626, the code would be, actually the solution:

```
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: "hi-world",
    properties:{
      name: {
        type: String,
        value: "default";
      },
      edad: {
        type: Number;
      }
    },
    created: function(){
      console.log("The element was created")
      console.log(this)
      console.log(this.$)
      //console.log(this.$.title) <-- commented, it collapses with created method
    }
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have placed `created callback` inside the properties object. And during created callback elements are not prepared so you won't find using `this.$.id`

Comment: Perfect! According to your suggest, I edit my code and repost it